# Field or Property 'Url' does not exist

Tags: client-object-model

Can someone help me understand why I am unable to get the "Url" property from this example? I get the error "Field or Property 'Url' does not exist":

```
        ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext("http://<weburl>");
        WebCollection allWebs = ctx.Web.Webs;

        var webCollection = ctx.LoadQuery(
            allWebs.Include(
                web => web.Title,
                web => web.ServerRelativeUrl,
                web => web.Url            
            )
        );

        ctx.ExecuteQuery();
        foreach (Web w in webCollection)
        {
            //w.ServerRelativeUrl returns a value, but
            //w.Url gives me an error. why?
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error occurs since you are using [SharePoint Server 2013 Client Components SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=35585) (ver. 15)  or [SharePoint Online Client Components SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42038) (ver. 16) but against SharePoint **2010**.

`Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Web` `Url Property` was introduced in CSOM ver. **15**

### How to determine Web Url in SharePoint 2010

The following example demonstrates how to get sub webs url in SharePoint 2010:

```
var webs = ctx.LoadQuery(
            ctx.Web.Webs.Include(
                web => web.Title,
                web => web.ServerRelativeUrl
            )
        );
ctx.Load(ctx.Site, s => s.Url);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();

foreach (Web web in webs)
{
    var webUrl = ctx.Site.Url + web.ServerRelativeUrl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`URL` is not a property of `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Web` however, `ServerRelativeUrl` is.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.web_properties(v=office.14).aspx

What are you trying to accomplish?